# How to mock properly classes and methods from imported modules

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to create some unitary tests for a method that needs to instantiate some objects using classes from external modules that I don't want to use, as they need arguments that I can't pass at object initialization.

For example, imagine that the code I want to test has the following structure:

```
from module_one import Class_1
from module_two import Class_2

class MyMainClass()
    def method_to_be_tested(self, stuff):
        var_one = Class_1(stuff.data)
        self.var_two = Class_2(var_one.data)
        print("The var is %s" % self.var_two.attribute)
```

`stuff` is a complex argument, with several attributes that I can't mock.

This is what I have tried in my test method, using `patch` from `unittest.mock` (but it didn't work):

```
@patch('module_two.Class_2')
@patch('module_one.Class_1')
def test_method(self, mocked_class1, mocked_class2):
    stuff = mock()
    mocked_class1.return_value = 'some_stuff_that_i_dont_want'
    mock_class2 = mock()
    mock_class2.attribute = 'what_i_want_to_get'
    mocked_class2 = mock_class2
    mymainclass.method_to_be_tested(stuff)
    assertEqual('what_i_want_to_get', mymainclass.var_two.attribute)
```

It seems that the patch or something isn't working, as  it throws an error telling me that *str object has no attribute data*, referring to `var_one` when `var_one.data` is used as an argument for `Class2`.

**What I want is to pass any argument to `Class2` and get always what I defined in `mock_class2`.**

**Edit:** `mock()` is imported from `mockito` module, but maybe I don't need this to achieve what I need.

Comment: I do not think you should be setting `mocked_class1.return_value`. Anyway what do you want to test here? You are not making any assertions.

Comment: Edited with the assertion. I want to check that `var_two.attribute` is `what_i_want_to_get`. The problem isn't in the `mocked_class1`, it's in the `Class2`, which seems to need the argument that I don't have, even if I use `patch`. As I said, what I want here is to get always the same value when I pass any argument to `Class2`, even if the argument that I use in the `method_to_be_tested` does not exist. I mean, what I really would like in my test is to assign directly the value that I want to `var_two`. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: What is `mock`? There is a module `unittest.mock` but of course it is not callable so `stuff = mock() ` raises `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` or just `NameError: name 'mock' is not defined` for me.

Comment: "str object has no attribute data, referring to var_one" of course, you have ``var_one = Class_1(stuff.data)` and you are patching `Class_1` to return a string, so `var_one` becomes a string and it does not have a `data` attribute.

Comment: `mock` is imported from `mockito` module (sorry, I should have specified it). Is there any way to make `Class2(var_one.data)` return what I want even if `var_one` does not have expected attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do that without mockito. Assuming that `MyMainClass` is defined in module `mainmodule`:

```
import unittest.mock as mock


class TestMyMainClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('mainmodule.Class_2')
    @mock.patch('mainmodule.Class_1')
    def test_method(self, mocked_class1, mocked_class2):
        stuff = mock.Mock()
        mocked_class2_instance = mock.Mock()
        mocked_class2_instance.attribute = 'what_i_want_to_get'
        mocked_class2.return_value = mocked_class2_instance
        mymainclass = MyMainClass()
        mymainclass.method_to_be_tested(stuff)
        self.assertEqual('what_i_want_to_get', mymainclass.var_two.attribute)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now if you think this test sucks, I have to agree.

- You have to patch `Class_1`, yet it doesn't even appear in the test.
- It is not obvious why `Class_2` is relevant at all unless you are familiar with the internal implementation details of the method under test. Actually you are testing implementation details instead of (or in addition to) observable behavior, which is usually bad.
- The behavior of the method depends (hopefully) on `stuff.data` but the test ignores that and will happily pass whatever it is. An yet you need a `stuff` object with a `data` attribute even if you don't care about what it is.

The main problem here is that by instantiating `Class_1` and `Class_2` inside the method you are tightly coupling the three pieces of code but now you want to test them in isolation. That's going to be hard and will probably lead to fragile and hard to read tests.

If you really want your code to be like that I suggest you test the method without mocking neither `Class_1` nor `Class_2`. Now if you say you don't want to do that because `stuff` (or better, `stuff.data`; why are you passing the whole think when you only need the data?) is hard to mock or instantiate, I would guess that there is a problem with your design, but that is as far as I can get from your contrived example.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that the problem was in a mess with the imports from other module. Thanks also for the advice, but this is part of a test that I tried to simplify (maybe I made it harder to understand), so your answer it's okay for what I need 